# Does this cause a real problem when I adopt the Raft's "never commits log entries from previous terms by counting replicas" rule in this situation?

Tags: distributed-system, consensus, raft

I am currently implementing the Raft consensus algorithm myself, and I meet with the following problem.
Consider there are 4 nodes(A, B, C and D), so a log entry can be committed with more than 2 votes. Now we start the cluster and have Leader A elected with `term = 0`. Then the following things happen:

1. Follower B/D disconnect.
2. Leader A create `LogEntry` X.
3. Leader A try to replicate to all nodes and fails eventually because only 2 nodes(A and C).
4. Node B reconnect and timeout, it starts a election with new `term = 1`.
5. Node A lost its leadership, because it received Node B's `RequestVote` RPC.
6. Node B can't win the election, because it has no `LogEntry` X. So there are no Leader in the cluster.
7. Node A timeout and be elected as Leader again.
8. Leader A successfully replicate `LogEntry` X to B.
9. Now node A/B/C have exactly the same `LogEntry` X, which is `(index = 0, term = 0)`. However, according to the Raft paper, Leader A can't commit X, though it's generated by itself and a majority agreed on X.

   > Raft never commits log entries from previous terms by counting
   >   replicas. Only log entries from the leader’s current term are
   >   committed by counting replicas;
10. Suppose there are no more `LogEntry`s from client to replicate, so `LogEntry` X remains uncommitted.

My questions are:

1. Is this a real problem?
2. Are there some solutions to this?
   In fact there are already some posts over SoF which emphasize the importance of this rule. And in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223417/how-does-raft-handle-committing-entries-from-previous-one), it seems to say we can create a copy Y of X, and replicate Y. Does it work or maybe there exists a common solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No
2. Yes. In raft paper, on page 13., you have the following:

> The Leader Completeness
>   Property guarantees that a leader has all committed entries, but at the start of its term, it may not know which
>   those are. To find out, it needs to commit an entry from
>   its term. Raft handles this by having each leader commit a blank no-op entry into the log at the start of its
>   term

In your case, after step 7., `A` will create a `NoOp` Log entry and it will succeed in replicating it, commit it and thus all previous entries will be committed.